# Computing median of 1-current line using hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I'm new to hadoop. Just finished reading the word count example, and have some ideas of what mappers and reducers do. However, what I learnt from the word count example seems not apply to my task, here's my task:

Given a document of multiple lines, e.g.,

hi

hello world

how are you

Output the median number of how many words each line has for every 1 to current lines, e.g.,

1

1.5

2

As they are median of {1}, median of {1,2}, median of {1,2,3}.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't easily parallelizable because each line result depends on all the lines before it. Technically you can do this with MR but just using a single mapper and no reducers, though that doesn't really prove anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the byte offset as key so that reducer will get it in the order
Use single reducer
In the reducer cache the previous median and no of lines processed so far 
Calculate the median by multiplying previous no of lines by previous median and current line no of words

Comment: How can I access the byte offset? i.e., if my mapper is now looking at the 1000th line, how can I print out this number 1000?

Comment: Hi, the default textinputformat provides (key,value) as (byteoffset, line) so the key you receive in mapper is the byte offset.